# How can I bypass the value of previous page to next page in Lightning community page by LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning-community, guest-user

I'm thinking about storing data in custom objects and contact with the permission of a guest user in the Lightning community (to be developed at LWC).  However, before storing it, I would like the user who entered the data on the confirmation screen to confirm it and correct it if there is an error in the data.  In the case of force.com site, the value can be retained in the global variable even between different pages in the common Apex controller, but how should I implement it in LWC?

Comment: Does the confirmation interface really need to be a separate page with its own separate URL?  You could make your life easier by creating a conditionally rendered confirmation subcomponent in your main data entry component.  Maybe a modal?

Answer (score 1):

You could have thought of [Lightning message service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_message_channel_considerations) to communicate across the DOM—between Visualforce pages, Aura components, and Lightning web components, Unfortunately, it is not supported in Lightning Communities.

As a workaround, You have two options:-

> [Window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) The sessionStorage property accesses a
> session Storage object for the current origin. sessionStorage is
> similar to localStorage; the difference is that while data in
> localStorage doesn't expire, data in sessionStorage is cleared when
> the page session ends.

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
let data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');

// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem('key');

// Remove all saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.clear();
```

> and another one would be keep your Lightning component structure in
> such a way that user don't need to navigate, you can conditionally
> render the HTML element.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I also thought that I had no choice but to process it with sessionStorage or to process the render process of the component.
However, I think that the information stored in salesforce includes personal information (phone number, address, deposit amount, etc.) and should not be used.
There was a problem that the object data could not be passed from the parent to the child component when performing the render process while communicating the events between the components under the condition. If there is a solution, please let me know.@sanket kumar

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/311909/how-can-i-pass-object-data-from-parent-to-child-component