# How can I pass object data from parent to child component?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-components

I'm trying to pass the data(object) from parent to child component but I got undefined on my child component's variable when I passed the data(object) from parent to child.

```html
/* Child Component*/
<template>
    <lightning-input label="Name" value={rec.Name} onchange={handleChangeName}></lightning-input>
    <lightning-button label="Next" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

```
/* Child Component JavaScript */
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class InputName extends LightningElement {

    @api rec = {
        Name: '',
        Phone: '',
        Industry: ''
    }


    handleChangeName(event){
        this.rec.Name = event.target.value;
        console.log(this.rec.Name);
    }
    handleClick(event){
        console.log('dispatched from child to parent component');
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('next', {detail: this.rec}));
        
    }
}
```

```html
/* Parent Component  */
<template>
    <template if:false={inputPhone}>
        <c-input-name onnext={nextInputName} rec={rec} ></c-input-name>
    </template>
</template>
```

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class Container extends LightningElement {

    @track inputPhone = false;

    @track rec = {
        Name: '',
        Phone:'',
        Industry:''
    }

    
    nextInputName(event){
        console.log('start event from <c-input-name> component');
        this.rec.Name = event.detail.Name;
        console.log(`from <c-input-name> component's value: ${this.rec.Name}`);
        this.inputPhone = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Data passed from the parent is mutated in the child so you can not edit that. Are you getting any error here?

Comment: I can't see the error, but when I try to print rec.Name in console.log, it always shows undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have gone through your code and played with it in the [playground here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/LbQvhOyXS/20/edit). So basically you are passing an empty object to child and trying to change the value passed by parent in child js controller.

According to [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_data_flow):-

> To prevent code complexity and unexpected side effects, data should
> flow in one direction, from parent to child.
>
> When a component decorates a field with @api to expose it as a public
> property, it should set the value only when it initializes the field.
> After the field is initialized, only the owner component should set
> the value. A component should treat values passed to it as read-only.
> To trigger a mutation for a property value provided by an owner
> component, a child component can send an event to the parent. If the
> parent owns the data, the parent can change the property value, which
> propagates down to the child component via the one-way data binding.

You have two options, either you send the input value in the payload of a custom event like this:-

```
   handleChangeName(event){
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('valuechange', {detail: event.target.value}));
        console.log('this.rec.Name '+this.rec.Name);
  }
```

and set the value in parent like this:-

```
<template>
    <template if:false={inputPhone}>
        <c-child onvaluechange={handleValueChange} onnext={nextInputName} rec={rec} ></c-child>
    </template>
</template>
```

and

```
handleValueChange(event){
        this.rec.Name = event.detail;
        console.log(this.rec.Name);
    }
```

2nd option would be to set the value of the public property in child itself:-

```
handleChangeName(event){
        //Option 2
        this.rec = {
            Name: event.target.value,
            Phone: '',
            Industry: ''
        };
        console.log('this.rec.Name '+this.rec.Name);
    }
```

Comment: Thank for you answer.